# Application takes time to open and turns blank or freezes when opened immediately after it is closed?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I am working on application in Android where screen turns black or freezes when opened immediately after closing it. As a result it takes time for launcher activity to launch.

I saw GC running in log but if application is closed why GC is running as a result my app shows black screen which is very annoying.

```
 J10-20 12:49:30.700: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 504K, 9% free 10465K/11412K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
 10-20 12:49:30.880: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 494K, 9% free 10472K/11412K, paused 24ms, total 24ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.040: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 534K, 9% free 10450K/11412K, paused 24ms, total 24ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.170: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 510K, 9% free 10451K/11412K, paused 25ms, total 25ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.270: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 487K, 9% free 10476K/11412K, paused 27ms, total 27ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.430: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 544K, 9% free 10443K/11412K, paused 27ms, total 27ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.551: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 510K, 9% free 10444K/11412K, paused 25ms, total 25ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.701: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 504K, 9% free 10450K/11412K, paused 24ms, total 24ms 
 10-20 12:49:31.811: D/dalvikvm(29875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 515K, 9% free 10447K/11412K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
```

This is what I get.
I get this in log.

How to avoid apart from using ViewHolder patterns and less creation of objects?

Added code of launcher activity:

```
    Log.i("Debug", "OnCreate Splas");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper_one_splash);

    Log.i("Debug", "Start Splash");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            WallpaperOneUtils utils = new WallpaperOneUtils(
                    WallpaperOneSplashActivity.this);
            Log.i("Debug", "Call for Internet Availability");
            if (utils.isInternetAvailable()) {
                Log.i("Debug", "Before All Category fetch");
                ParseManagerUtil.getUniqueInstance()
                        .getAllCategoriesForApplication();
                Intent startingActivity = new Intent(
                        WallpaperOneSplashActivity.this,
                        HomeScreenActivity.class);
                Log.i("Debug", "After All Category fetch");
                startActivity(startingActivity);
            } else {
                Intent noInternet = new Intent(
                        WallpaperOneSplashActivity.this,
                        ErrorActivity.class);
                startActivity(noInternet);
            }

        }
    }, 2 * 1000);
```

Comment: are you doing something heavy on UI thread?

Comment: no all my operations are on Async task like network calls etc. and can we stop all async task for given activity if activity is stopped

Comment: can you please post code ?

Comment: can you please post the code, what are you doing in your on create of launcher activity

Comment: edit question to add code of launcher activity.

Comment: actually I have application class which is called before Launcher class so after the code in Application class is executed GC runs and then launcher activity is launched as a result it takes time to load main activity.

Comment: You can try to put the code of your thread in `onResume` method

Comment: @Groco which code and onResume of ? Same blank screen comes when there are many items in Gridview and on click of item it takes time for viewpager to open as i want to show each item of gridview in VIewpgager which has FragmentPagerAdapter implemented

Comment: Okay the idea was that your operation in the thread was pretty long. But if you've got GC it's maybe a recycling issue. Do you use convertView in your getView of your gridView's adapter?

Comment: public View getView(int postion, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   // View v = view;
   ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

   if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup,
      false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.picture = (ImageView) view
      .findViewById(R.id.picture);
    // view.setTag(R.id.picture, view.findViewById(R.id.picture));
    // view.setTag(R.id.progress, view.findViewById(R.id.progress));
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
   } else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
   }


This is my code in gridview adapter

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use ViewHolder? Try to do it like this in your adapter:

```
public View getView(int postion, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
{ 

    if (view == null) 
    { 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false); 
    } 

    view.setImageResource(...);

    return view;
}
```